# How do l capture selected data from a jquery dropdown in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to take the value of the selected item and put it in my database using laravel PHP, can someone advice on how I can capture the selected value.

```
<script>
$("#maid").ddslick({
    width:"100%",
    selectText: "Select your social network",
    imagePosition:"left",
    onSelected: function(data){
    $("#selected").html(data.selectedData.value);
    }
});
</script>




 <select name="maid_id" id="maid" class="form-control"{{ isset($listing) && $listing->live() ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' }}>
    @foreach ($maids as $maid)

        <optgroup label="{{ $maid->name }}">
            @foreach ($maid->children as $child)

                @if (isset($listing) && $listing->maid_id == $child->id || old('maid_id') == $child->id   )
                    <option  value="{{ $child->id }}" data-imagesrc="/image/billion.png"

                    data-description="This Cleaner is available" selected="selected" @php echo "$child->status" @endphp>{{ $child->name }} </option>
                @else
                    <option   value="{{ $child->id }}" data-imagesrc="/image/billion.png"

                    data-description="This Cleaner is available" @php echo "$child->status" @endphp>{{ $child->name }}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </optgroup>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: can you add your `html` code as well

Comment: Yes l added my Html and php looping through options from DB